# Kafka has 100% under-replicated partitions on some topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Using Kafka 0.9.0.1.

There's topic with 22 replicas, 50 partitions and 100% under-replicated as seen in Kafka Manager.

There are 22 brokers. One broker is a leader of 49 replicas and another for 1.

How to understand the reason for 100% under-replicated status and fix this?

I tried to generate and run partition assignment, but it's getting stuck and need to unblock it from zookeeper. Tried it several times.

Comment: Did you create the topic while all 22 brokers were running or did you increased the number of brokers over time?

Comment: The topic was created while some of the 22 brokers were running. They fail sometimes, new are added.

Comment: Please add the output of `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe ...`